# TypeScript Generic Constraint and 'keyof'

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a class where I want the end-user to be able to specify a map of (arbitrary, user-defined) names for (arbitrary, user-defined) configuration objects that will type different properties and methods inside the class through generics.

My current working implementation looks like this:

```ts
// Configs should be objects. Primitives not allowed
// Incidentally, is there a better way to constrain a generic to be an object?
type ModConfig = Record<string, any>

type Operation<N extends string, C extends ModConfig> = {
    mod: N,
    config: C,
    status: string,
}

class Controller<N extends string, M extends Record<string, ModConfig>> {
    activeModule: N;

    private opsByMod: Operation<N, M[N]>[] = []

    private configs: { [K in N]?: M[K] } = {}

    constructor(startMod: N) {
        this.activeModule = startMod
    }

    addConfig<K extends N>(mod: K, config: M[K]) {
        this.configs[mod] = config;
    }
}

// Sample usage

interface ModAConfig {
    aNumber: number,
    aString: string,
}

interface ModBConfig {
    bBoolean: boolean,
    bObject: {
        bNested: string,
    }
}

type myModules = 'moduleA' | 'moduleB'

const cInstance = new Controller<myModules, { moduleA: ModAConfig, moduleB: ModBConfig }>('moduleA')
```

While this works, I would like to remove the generic param `N` as it is redundant if I could just use `keyof M`. Like this:

```ts
class Controller<M extends Record<string, ModConfig>> {
    // This is no longer 'string' but 'string | number | symbol'
    activeModule: keyof M;

    // TS Error:
    //  Type 'keyof M' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.
    //  Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'
    private opsByMod: Operation<keyof M, M[keyof M]>[] = []

    // This also now takes not only 'string' but 'string | number | symbol' as keys
    private configs: { [K in keyof M]?: M[K] } = {}

    constructor(startMod: keyof M) {
        this.activeModule = startMod
    }

    // Same deal
    addConfig<K extends keyof M>(mod: K, config: M[K]) {
        this.configs[mod] = config;
    }
}
```

However as I commented above, `keyof M` produces `string | number | symbol`. This seems to be because M **extends** `Record<string, ModConfig>` which I guess is interpreted as numbers/symbols potentially being added as keys by the extension being supplied as parameter for M.

Is there a way to do this so that M is constrained strictly to only being keyed by strings so I can just substitute `N` with `keyof M`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this type to extract only keys of `M` which are `strings`.

```
type StringKeys<T> = Extract<keyof T, string>
```

Everywhere in your code that you were using `keyof M`, replace it with `StringKeys<M>`.

Now it's still theoretically possible for M to contain number keys, but those keys can't be used for setting the `activeModule` or getting an `Operation`.

```
class Controller<M extends Record<string, ModConfig>> {
    activeModule: StringKeys<M>;

    private opsByMod: Operation<StringKeys<M>, M[StringKeys<M>]>[] = []

    private configs: { [K in StringKeys<M>]?: M[K] } = {}

    constructor(startMod: StringKeys<M>) {
        this.activeModule = startMod
    }

    addConfig<K extends StringKeys<M>>(mod: K, config: M[K]) {
        this.configs[mod] = config;
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGEHsDsDMEsDmBnUyAWkCuAbAJqAEYCmokhAVsQMYAuyAdKAAoBO8AtvLfAG7GpokWqACGOHJADuxPACgQoAJLRq8PMWi1xOAJ4AaUPFS10xVqVFFitWudBTRu0LUihqMZLVaj40MaCImubw1C5uJGL%205FR0APxytLoADqQAspB4UHBIoAC8oABKNJCseAA8XuzQiIai0LoAfHKJKaQA8qk%20PDDlAHKgxAAedtB4qFV%20tRCDI5rjoBlZMAiIjfmgAN5yoLugHJkAXKB9%20jt7HjmIx%20Bne2jatFjIx5M1ZwC%20LUmpoADK3imAGliLpkOUACrrAoAURGPjo5QA1qDILBQBDDG81i1qDhRMhUNlvJAJOZymlZqMFsUPGVKoD3otMtlVo11tt7qI6HxiEtcMRjgDqogQWCKY0ANwte7Jdi8UR2MjJZAAIV0S2OnXMivgvWFwNB4LSjUMaQA2gaamLjY0ALqNc12jZOmV7OV8RWkS6rF5bUDmoFGfxW0VGiV2uLHC1A50fDabL7nXaXKpYOilAAUXlErFomv%20jLD4pNAEotsn7i50MYGNyePx%20ThSAUc3mlpWk1y8MsruUg8NqahQzaJY1Mwc8McgYYfUho4G7eXOVXdqZa3OUObJ86CpvpfcvkmFGA-qIOMlm6BnqIgi0-HZWLBuelMgBBVm5Fe7UR9LAcEhWGOaB-0Au49lEUNXiLT57y0cxn2oV88FVT9EAre5CFVSBSWIepjkIHDm3qcDdkIdpKBoWhjm-KtCD6AQ7CnB4RVI0Aj2%20Np9g1TIBVQAoAHJJwFN8BNAAAfUAhN45tVQE3FPBEagVBzVQW1AaBiCkCAYBJMlWHKDgeLwPjDE2fYZOIN9o3fNDDGE2SbJQtD2KAA)

Comment: This I guess can take care of typing inside the Class, but it still allows for the user to be able to put 'invalid' entries in the map, those would just end up being ignored. Is there really no way to make a generic have to follow a specific type instead of extensions of that type?

Comment: @RobertoCuba Same problem, I either have function argument checked for invalid entries or I have the function return value's properties inferred correctly e.g. func().inferred but not both func({invalid: 1}.inferred